# Is there a way to hide the Box-Model Graphic in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to hide or remove the Box-Model Graphic at the top of the Computed tab above the Filters? It's the graphic that shows margin/border/padding and dimensions. It's not useful for me and I'd love to have the additional dozen lines of filters.

I spend about 4 hours every day in Chrome's Dev Tools and it's just one of those little frustrations it would be nice to fix.

This is an image of the box model graphic since I'm too new to posting to have a 10 reputation:

[image: This is an image of the box model graphic since I'm too new to posting to have a 10 reputation]

Comment: You can write a *custom theme for devtools* to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension for that exact purpose, because this was annoying me for too long now.

Here's my current solution (version **0.9.1**):

```
div.metrics { display: none; } 
.style-panes-wrapper > .vbox.flex-auto.flex-none { display: none; }
```

Put that into a CSS file in your extension, load it via JS, and you're basically done.

For everyone who doesn't want to re-invent the wheel, here is the devtools-extension I made: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/eoponiimbhcmaenjpdedhfknijgjcjcf

Cheers!

Comment: The extension doesn't hide the Box-Model for me but would love to use it if it did work. I've also enabled `Allow extensions to load custom stylesheets` in `DevTools` > `Experiments`.

Comment: @ttt I guess chrome changed something here. I updated my css rules to this now, which seems to work: div.metrics { display: none; }  .style-panes-wrapper > .vbox.flex-auto.flex-none { display: none; }
I updated the chrome extension, but it will take a while until it was approved.
You're free to check on it again and I hope it'll work for you then

Comment: It's working now. Thank you for the update. Great tool, saves space, can see more variables without scrolling. BTW... How do you find out the CSS of this box/where/how do you see the html/css code? In case I should have to manually change it in the extension in the case that Google changes it again.

Comment: You can open up the devtools, then undock them, and press CTRL+Shift+I again to open up their devtools

Comment: @ttt discovered a bug and fixed it. styles pane was missing contents. fixed in 0.9.2